# How does LLVM translate OpenMP multi-threaded code with runtime library calls?

Tags: clang, openmp, llvm, intel-mkl

When I studied the [LLVM OpenMP Runtime Library document](https://openmp.llvm.org/Reference.pdf), I found there is an example about work sharing:

```c
extern float foo( void );
int main () {
    int i;
    float r = 0.0;
    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic) reduction(+:r)
    for ( i = 0; i < 10; i ++ ) {
        r += foo();
    }
}
```

and then it shows the transformed code like below:

```c
extern float foo( void );
int main () {
    static int zero = 0;
    auto int gtid;
    auto float r = 0.0;
    __kmpc_begin( & loc3, 0 );
    // The gtid is not actually required in this example so could be omitted;
    // We show its initialization here because it is often required for calls into
    // the runtime and should be locally cached like this.
    gtid = __kmpc_global thread num( & loc3 );
    __kmpc_fork call( & loc7, 1, main_7_parallel_3, & r );
    __kmpc_end( & loc0 );
    return 0;
}

struct main_10_reduction_t_5 { float r_10_rpr; };

static kmp_critical_name lck = { 0 };
static ident_t loc10; // loc10.flags should contain KMP_IDENT_ATOMIC_REDUCE bit set
                      // if compiler has generated an atomic reduction.
void main_7_parallel_3( int *gtid, int *btid, float *r_7_shp ) {
    auto int i_7_pr;
    auto int lower, upper, liter, incr;
    auto struct main_10_reduction_t_5 reduce;
    reduce.r_10_rpr = 0.F;
    liter = 0;
    __kmpc_dispatch_init_4( & loc7,*gtid, 35, 0, 9, 1, 1 );
    while ( __kmpc_dispatch_next_4( & loc7, *gtid, & liter, & lower, & upper, & incr
      ) ) {
        for( i_7_pr = lower; upper >= i_7_pr; i_7_pr ++ )
          reduce.r_10_rpr += foo();
    }
    switch( __kmpc_reduce_nowait( & loc10, *gtid, 1, 4, & reduce, main_10_reduce_5, &lck ) ) {
        case 1:
           *r_7_shp += reduce.r_10_rpr;
           __kmpc_end_reduce_nowait( & loc10, *gtid, & lck );
           break;
        case 2:
           __kmpc_atomic_float4_add( & loc10, *gtid, r_7_shp, reduce.r_10_rpr );
           break;
        default:;
    }
}
```

I spent a lot of time to find how does OpenMP transform code like above, but still could not find the way to show the result like the example, and how it work in in OpenMP.

So, here is my question which make me confused for a long time:
Is there any way to output files or show the result directly like the example?

Comment: That's a great question. I wonder if you can get it partially by looking at the abstract syntax tree (AST) output.

Comment: Unfortunately `clang` does not seem to have options to print intermediate representations like GCC. @Zboson the AST doesn't seem to provide any insight (try `-cc1 -ast-print`).

Comment: @Zboson @Zulan Thank you for replying the question first! I already tried using `-ast-print` and `-ast-dump` to observe the AST nodes. But I still do not know how OpenMP translates the directive like `#pragma omp parallel` into the functions like `__kmpc_fork call(...)` etc.

Comment: @Yu-WenLai you can look at the assembly. That's what I normally do to find out what's really going on https://godbolt.org/z/sbO3Lb

Comment: The assembly seems very closed to the target that I needed. I will focus on studying the assembly. Thanks a lot, @Zboson!!

Answer (score 1):

You can inspect the LLVM IR (see https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html).

For example:

```
clang -fopenmp -O2 -emit-llvm -S -o - example.c
```

Will print the following  to stdout:

```
[...]
; Function Attrs: nounwind uwtable
define dso_local i32 @main() local_unnamed_addr #0 {
entry:
  %i = alloca i32, align 4
  %r = alloca float, align 4
  %0 = bitcast i32* %i to i8*
  call void @llvm.lifetime.start.p0i8(i64 4, i8* nonnull %0) #4
  %1 = bitcast float* %r to i8*
  call void @llvm.lifetime.start.p0i8(i64 4, i8* nonnull %1) #4
  store float 0.000000e+00, float* %r, align 4, !tbaa !2
  call void (%struct.ident_t*, i32, void (i32*, i32*, ...)*, ...) @__kmpc_fork_call(%struct.ident_t* nonnull @0, i32 2, void (i32*, i32*, ...)* bitcast (void (i32*, i32*, i32*, float*)* @.omp_outlined. to void (i32*, i32*, ...)*), i32* nonnull %i, float* nonnull %r) #4
  call void @llvm.lifetime.end.p0i8(i64 4, i8* nonnull %1) #4
  call void @llvm.lifetime.end.p0i8(i64 4, i8* nonnull %0) #4
  ret i32 0
}
[...]

; Function Attrs: norecurse nounwind uwtable
define internal void @.omp_outlined.(i32* noalias nocapture readonly %.global_tid., i32* noalias nocapture readnone %.bound_tid., i32* nocapture readnone dereferenceable(4) %i, float* nocapture dereferenceable(4) %r) #2 {
entry:
  %.omp.lb = alloca i32, align 4
  %.omp.ub = alloca i32, align 4
  %.omp.stride = alloca i32, align 4
  %.omp.is_last = alloca i32, align 4
  %r1 = alloca float, align 4
  %.omp.reduction.red_list = alloca [1 x i8*], align 8
  %0 = bitcast i32* %.omp.lb to i8*
  call void @llvm.lifetime.start.p0i8(i64 4, i8* nonnull %0) #4
  store i32 0, i32* %.omp.lb, align 4, !tbaa !6
  %1 = bitcast i32* %.omp.ub to i8*
  call void @llvm.lifetime.start.p0i8(i64 4, i8* nonnull %1) #4
  store i32 9, i32* %.omp.ub, align 4, !tbaa !6
  %2 = bitcast i32* %.omp.stride to i8*
  call void @llvm.lifetime.start.p0i8(i64 4, i8* nonnull %2) #4
  store i32 1, i32* %.omp.stride, align 4, !tbaa !6
  %3 = bitcast i32* %.omp.is_last to i8*
  call void @llvm.lifetime.start.p0i8(i64 4, i8* nonnull %3) #4
  store i32 0, i32* %.omp.is_last, align 4, !tbaa !6
  %4 = bitcast float* %r1 to i8*
  call void @llvm.lifetime.start.p0i8(i64 4, i8* nonnull %4) #4
  store float 0.000000e+00, float* %r1, align 4, !tbaa !2
  %5 = load i32, i32* %.global_tid., align 4, !tbaa !6
  tail call void @__kmpc_dispatch_init_4(%struct.ident_t* nonnull @0, i32 %5, i32 35, i32 0, i32 9, i32 1, i32 1) #4
  %6 = call i32 @__kmpc_dispatch_next_4(%struct.ident_t* nonnull @0, i32 %5, i32* nonnull %.omp.is_last, i32* nonnull %.omp.lb, i32* nonnull %.omp.ub, i32* nonnull %.omp.stride) #4
  %tobool14 = icmp eq i32 %6, 0
  br i1 %tobool14, label %omp.dispatch.end, label %omp.dispatch.body

omp.dispatch.cond.loopexit:                       ; preds = %omp.inner.for.body, %omp.dispatch.body
  %7 = call i32 @__kmpc_dispatch_next_4(%struct.ident_t* nonnull @0, i32 %5, i32* nonnull %.omp.is_last, i32* nonnull %.omp.lb, i32* nonnull %.omp.ub, i32* nonnull %.omp.stride) #4
  %tobool = icmp eq i32 %7, 0
  br i1 %tobool, label %omp.dispatch.end, label %omp.dispatch.body

omp.dispatch.body:                                ; preds = %entry, %omp.dispatch.cond.loopexit
  %8 = load i32, i32* %.omp.lb, align 4, !tbaa !6
  %9 = load i32, i32* %.omp.ub, align 4, !tbaa !6, !llvm.mem.parallel_loop_access !8
  %cmp12 = icmp sgt i32 %8, %9
  br i1 %cmp12, label %omp.dispatch.cond.loopexit, label %omp.inner.for.body

omp.inner.for.body:                               ; preds = %omp.dispatch.body, %omp.inner.for.body
  %.omp.iv.013 = phi i32 [ %add4, %omp.inner.for.body ], [ %8, %omp.dispatch.body ]
  %call = call float @foo() #4, !llvm.mem.parallel_loop_access !8
  %10 = load float, float* %r1, align 4, !tbaa !2, !llvm.mem.parallel_loop_access !8
  %add3 = fadd float %call, %10
  store float %add3, float* %r1, align 4, !tbaa !2, !llvm.mem.parallel_loop_access !8
  %add4 = add nsw i32 %.omp.iv.013, 1
  %11 = load i32, i32* %.omp.ub, align 4, !tbaa !6, !llvm.mem.parallel_loop_access !8
  %cmp = icmp slt i32 %.omp.iv.013, %11
  br i1 %cmp, label %omp.inner.for.body, label %omp.dispatch.cond.loopexit, !llvm.loop !8

omp.dispatch.end:                                 ; preds = %omp.dispatch.cond.loopexit, %entry
  %12 = bitcast [1 x i8*]* %.omp.reduction.red_list to float**
  store float* %r1, float** %12, align 8
  %13 = bitcast [1 x i8*]* %.omp.reduction.red_list to i8*
  %14 = call i32 @__kmpc_reduce_nowait(%struct.ident_t* nonnull @1, i32 %5, i32 1, i64 8, i8* nonnull %13, void (i8*, i8*)* nonnull @.omp.reduction.reduction_func, [8 x i32]* nonnull @.gomp_critical_user_.reduction.var) #4
  switch i32 %14, label %.omp.reduction.default [
    i32 1, label %.omp.reduction.case1
    i32 2, label %.omp.reduction.case2
  ]

.omp.reduction.case1:                             ; preds = %omp.dispatch.end
  %15 = load float, float* %r, align 4, !tbaa !2
  %16 = load float, float* %r1, align 4, !tbaa !2
  %add5 = fadd float %15, %16
  store float %add5, float* %r, align 4, !tbaa !2
  call void @__kmpc_end_reduce_nowait(%struct.ident_t* nonnull @1, i32 %5, [8 x i32]* nonnull @.gomp_critical_user_.reduction.var) #4
  br label %.omp.reduction.default

.omp.reduction.case2:                             ; preds = %omp.dispatch.end
  %17 = bitcast float* %r to i32*
  %atomic-load = load atomic i32, i32* %17 monotonic, align 4, !tbaa !2
  %18 = load float, float* %r1, align 4, !tbaa !2
  br label %atomic_cont

atomic_cont:                                      ; preds = %atomic_cont, %.omp.reduction.case2
  %19 = phi i32 [ %atomic-load, %.omp.reduction.case2 ], [ %23, %atomic_cont ]
  %20 = bitcast i32 %19 to float
  %add7 = fadd float %18, %20
  %21 = bitcast float %add7 to i32
  %22 = cmpxchg i32* %17, i32 %19, i32 %21 monotonic monotonic
  %23 = extractvalue { i32, i1 } %22, 0
  %24 = extractvalue { i32, i1 } %22, 1
  br i1 %24, label %.omp.reduction.default, label %atomic_cont

.omp.reduction.default:                           ; preds = %atomic_cont, %.omp.reduction.case1, %omp.dispatch.end
  call void @llvm.lifetime.end.p0i8(i64 4, i8* nonnull %4) #4
  call void @llvm.lifetime.end.p0i8(i64 4, i8* nonnull %3) #4
  call void @llvm.lifetime.end.p0i8(i64 4, i8* nonnull %2) #4
  call void @llvm.lifetime.end.p0i8(i64 4, i8* nonnull %1) #4
  call void @llvm.lifetime.end.p0i8(i64 4, i8* nonnull %0) #4
  ret void
}
[...]
```

Comment: The LLVM IR code seems very clear to know how the OpenMP pragma does. You have been a great help, thank you so much!